# Not able to create View on Hive table using HiveContext. Getting DBLock Manager issue

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am not able to create View on Hive table using `HiveContext`. Facing DBLock Manager Lock issue. Same View creation query works fine in Hive Beeline. But its failing when executed using Hive Context.

> 17/02/23 10:44:18 INFO metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI 
>   thrift://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
>   17/02/23 10:44:18 INFO metastore: Connected to metastore.
>   17/02/23 10:44:18 INFO DbLockManager: Response to queryId=XXXXXXXX_20170223104411_2b1a475e-ad6d-45b3-8ec6-6a30a9123664 LockResponse(lockid:419, state:WAITING)